# Unity account login without desktop environment

Tags: unity

when i install GLX-Dock (Cairo-Dock with openGL) my unity desktop environment crashed and there is nothing except with the background image. i thought due to ccsm and also i had already install and runned Avant Window navigator. my others accounts like gnome and unity 2d runs as they were. how can i again make work unity.

Answer (score 1):

Running `unity --reset` should fix most Unity issues.

- [How do I reset my Unity configuration?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17610/how-do-i-reset-my-unity-configuration)

Answer (score 0):

Try re-naming your .config folder to something like .config-backup, removing cairo-dock, and rebooting.